How to analyze a current sink for an ideal power amplifier
In preparing a design for a MOSFET RF Power Amplifier, I analyzed this idealized circuit:

My analysis is in some ways consistent with simulation but in some ways gets very different results.  Is my analysis correct? If so, why does it not agree with simulation.
Analysis shows: $$ V_{out} = I_{src} \omega^2 LCR_{load}$$ since
$$
I_{src} = I_0 e^{j \omega t} \
V_{L} = V_1 - L \frac{dI_{src}}{dt} \
= V_1 -jI_{src} \omega L$$
$$V_{out} = I_{load}R_{load} \\
I_{load} = C \frac{dV_{L}}{dt} \\
= \omega^2 L C I_{src} \\
V_{out} = I_{src} \omega^2 LCR_{load}.
$$
This suggests that \$V_{out}\$ is linear in \$L, C, R\$ and quadratic in \$f\$ and should be in phase with \$I_{src}\$. However, when I simulate it, I find that:

Doubling \$R_{load}\$ only raises \$V_{out}\$ by \$\approx 70\%\$
Doubling \$L1\$ almost doubles \$V_{out}\$ but not quite
Doubling \$f\$ is expected to quadruple \$V_{out}\$, and actually does more than quadruple!
Phase is off by a few degrees

Is my analysis correct? If so, why the discrepancies?

Doubling f is expected to quadruple Vout, and actually does more than quadruple!   Try an AC sweep; at which f is Vout maximum?  What is this maximum?  Does your theory predict this result?  For results closer to reality, suggest including some real-world parasitics in the L and C, eg: series and parallel R for both.

An AC sweep is not advanced analysis.  Transient non-steady state analysis, ie: what waveforms you would see on a scope, is far more complex.  A simple test tells me the formula for Vout (as a function of Isrc, f, L, C, R) is incorrect regarding its dependence on f.  As f goes from low to high value, beyond some value of f the change in output voltage will be negligible - it will not continue upwards infinitely.

The math you presented is confusing: 1. too many "=" on the same line.  2. What is "VL", is it voltage across inductor or voltage across the load resistor?  No means by which I can identify each step of your analysis, makes it hard for anyone to tell you, for example, "equation 3 has error"

It's hard to understand how your equations relate to the physical circuit because you haven't told us what variables like \$V_L\$ represent.
But I can tell there is something wrong with this step:

$$
I_{src} = I_0 e^{j \omega t} \
V_{L} = V_1 - L \frac{dI_{src}}{dt} \
= V_1 -jI_{src} \omega L$$

You seem to be mixing up transient or instantaneous-time variables and solutions with AC steady-state variables and solutions.
When you use the imaginary unit j it implies you are considering an AC steady-state solution with oscillating voltages or currents represented by complex-valued phasors.
But you have included \$V_1\$ in your solution, which is the voltage of a DC source, and therefore should have no place in an AC solution.
If you want an AC steady-state (phasor) solution you should replace the DC source by its AC equivalent (a short circuit). If you want a transient solution you should not have complex numbers in your equations.
(Conceivably you are trying to solve the transient system with a complex exponential stimulus, which is sometimes done in advanced signal analysis, but is not a common technique for simple RLC circuits, and not what your instructor will expect in a course where you would study the circuit you presented)
You also have

$$I_{load} = C \frac{dV_{L}}{dt} $$

Which is (assuming \$V_L\$ is the voltage at the upper terminal of the sinusoidal source, which it must be for some of your other equations to be valid) not correct.
It should be
$$I_{load} = C \frac{d(V_{L}-V_{out})}{dt} $$
because the capacitor is connected between nodes L and out, not between node L and ground.
I suspect this second issue is the actual source of your error.

Thanks! This is very helpful.  I'm working on redoing the analysis based on what you said.  One question: "you have included V1 in your solution, which is the voltage of a DC source, and therefore should have no place in an AC solution."  Perhaps I'm not understanding properly, but a DC voltage of $k$ volts is equal to $ke^{0jt} = k$; why should it be excluded from the analysis? If I want to know the voltage at a point, and I know the starting voltage (fixed, DC, $k$), and I know the drop to that point, I sum them to get the voltage at the point.  What's wrong with that?

@SRobertJames, in an AC analysis, you solve for each frequency component separately, so if you're solving for the response to the 1 MHz source, the DC voltage source should be treated as a short circuit.

Your analysis must be wrong if it doesn't correspond with my simulated AC analysis using micro-cap 12 (that's the download link should you prefer to use a better simulator): -

For a ten times increase in frequency, the output level rises a hundred times but, only up to the point of resonance, Above that the circuit has a fixed amplitude output for any increase in frequency i.e. your circuit is a high pass filter: -

The fixed amplitude I refer to in my previous paragraph is at 33.97 dB and, that is exactly the voltage level you would get when feeding 1 amp into a 50 Ω resistor or, put another way 50 volts has a dB value of 33.97 dB relative to 1 volt.
You should also note that the 10 volt DC source is irrelevant for any AC analysis of this type hence, I've grounded the inductor.

Thank you.  Why do you think the equations I used give results inconsistent with this? The equations are standard, the math seems correct, and the results are reasonable - why do they differ from your simulation?

Or perhaps more to the point: Analytically, can you show why the the output levels off at a frequency, instead of continuing to grow with increases in frequency?

@SRobertJames well, given that you didn't say how far the difference was between what your simulator told you and what your equations predict it's anyone's guess. I have offered my simulation to help you understand as well as pointing out that my simulation is spot on so, any difference you see is pointing towards an error on your part. Analytically I can show how a 2nd order high-pass filter works, yes. However, that is something you can do for yourself by using proper circuit theorems. Maybe you should raise that as a new post?

Well, let's analyze the following circuit:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
When we use and apply KCL, we can write the following set of equations:
$$\text{I}_1=\text{I}_0+\text{I}_2\tag1$$
When we use and apply Ohm's law, we can write the following set of equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$
Substituting \$\displaystyle(2)\$ into \$\displaystyle(1)\$, gives:
$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}&=\text{I}_0+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}&=\text{I}_0+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$
Solving for \$\displaystyle\text{V}_2\$, gives:
$$\text{V}_2=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}\left(\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{I}_0\text{R}_1\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}+\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\tag4$$
Using Laplace transform, we get:
$$\text{v}_2\left(t\right)=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}\left(\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}}{\displaystyle\text{s}}-\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\text{i}}_0\omega}{\text{s}^2+\omega^2}\cdot\text{sL}\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}+\text{sL}+\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}}}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\tag5$$
Now, when we assume your values and \$\displaystyle\hat{\text{i}}_0=1\space\text{A}\$, we get:
$$\hat{\text{v}}_2\left(\text{R}=50\space\Omega\right)=\frac{\displaystyle100}{\displaystyle\sqrt{248629}}\approx0.200551\space\text{V}\tag6$$
$$\hat{\text{v}}_2\left(\text{R}=100\space\Omega\right)=50\sqrt{\frac{\displaystyle2}{\displaystyle31313}}\approx0.399597\space\text{V}\tag7$$
Which, gives:
$$\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\text{v}}_2\left(\text{R}=100\space\Omega\right)}{\displaystyle\hat{\text{v}}_2\left(\text{R}=50\space\Omega\right)}=\sqrt{\frac{\displaystyle248629}{\displaystyle62626}}\approx1.9925\tag8$$

Edit, I will edit my Mathematia-code into here, so that you can check it for yourself and experiment with more values of \$\displaystyle\text{R}\$:
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
ParallelTable[{R,
  u = 10;
  i = 1;
  c = 1*10^(-9);
  L = 4*10^(-6);
  w = 10^6;
  FullSimplify[
   Maximize[
     FullSimplify[
       InverseLaplaceTransform[(R*((u/s) - ((i*w)/(s^2 + w^2))*s*
              L))/(R + s*L + (1/(s*c))), s, t]] /. {Exp[_] -> 0}, t] //
     First]}, {R, 50, 100, 50}]

Out[1]={{50, 100/Sqrt[248629]}, {100, 50 Sqrt[2/31313]}}

In[2]:=FullSimplify[(50 Sqrt[2/31313])/(100/Sqrt[248629])]

Out[2]=Sqrt[248629/62626]

In[3]:=N[%2]

Out[3]=1.9925


The ratio V2(100) / V2(50) should be around 1.71 @ 1MHz. Although the DC source Vi affects the total RMS voltage across the current sink, it is not relevant at all for the voltage at the load because "R2" is a capacitor, a DC-blocking component.

@Raonoke well, it isn't. It is around 1.99.

Well, it should ;-).

@Raonoke Circuitlab gives a value close to 1.7, as you predict.  But where is the error in my analysis?

@SRobertJames Do you want the mathematica code I used to verify my solution? I know that that one is right.

The 10V DC supply voltage doesn't contribute to the voltage at the load and can be replaced by a short.
With a 50 Ohm load at the output, the current sink works into an impedance of Zs = 1.55 + j29.3.
Assuming a current sink with Is = 1A(rms), the (AC) voltage magnitude developed across the sink is Vs = Is * |Zs| = 1A * 29.34 Ohm = 29.34V.
This voltage is split between the 1nF cap and the 50 Ohm load. The voltage across the load would be Vload = Vs * cos (phi) = 8.8V with phi = arctan (Xc/Rload) = 72.6°.
When the output load is doubled to 100 Ohm, the current sink is now loaded with Zs' = 2.26 + j28.2 Ohm and develops a voltage magnitude Vs' = 28.3V across it's terminals.
The voltage at the load is now Vload' = 15.1V, a 71% increase (factor n=1.71) from the output voltage with 50 Ohm load.
